# jquery: if url contains #work then do something

Tags: jquery, url, contain

I tried to write a script which allow me to load certain events when I enter specific url.

My code looks like this:

```
$(function(){
    var url = window.location.pathname;
    $("url:contains('#Work')").animate({"left": "250"}, "slow");
});
```

But it doesnt work. Any suggestions? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You shouldn't use an url to begin with

Answer (score 47, accepted):

```
$(function() {
    if ( document.location.href.indexOf('#Work') > -1 ) {
        $('#elementID').animate({"left": "250"}, "slow");
    }
});
```

Comment: _Note for passers-by:_ searching a string will return `0` if found at the beginning and `-1` if not found. It works in this case because the fragment will never be at the beginning of the URL, but generally you should search strings with `> -1` or `>= 0`.

Answer (score 11):

window.location.href is pulling the URL into a variable, so you can't search for #Work using that method. Try:

```
var url = window.location.href;

if (url.search("#Work") >= 0) {
    //found it, now do something
}
```

Comment: _Note for passers-by:_ searching a string will return `0` if found at the beginning and `-1` if not found. It works in this case because the fragment will never be at the beginning of the URL, but generally you should search strings with `> -1` or `>= 0`.