# how to set div display property block when url have some id?

Tags: jquery, css

how to set  div display property block when url have some id?

i want to set div display property none to block when url have id `#showcity`

example

CSS

```
 .city{
     width:200px;
     height:200px; 
     background: red;
     display: none; 
}
```

HTML

```
 <div>some data </div>
 <div class="city">Some city</div>
```

I want to show city(`display:block`) when url hit like `example.com/#showcity`

how can i do this?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:target

Comment: possible duplicate of [jquery: if url contains #work then do something](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5757362/jquery-if-url-contains-work-then-do-something)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you looking something like this:

```
 if (window.location.href.indexOf("#showcity") > -1) {
    $(".city").css('display','block');
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply give an `id` of `showcity` to the div element, then use [`:target`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:target) pseudo-class to make it visible:

```
<div id="showcity" class="city">Some city</div>
```

```css
.city:target {
  display: block;
}
```

> **[6.6.2. The target pseudo-class :target](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#target-pseudo)**
>
> Some URIs refer to a location within a resource. This kind of URI ends
>   with a "number sign" (#) followed by an anchor identifier (called the
>   fragment identifier).
>
> URIs with fragment identifiers link to a certain element within the
>   document, known as the target element. For instance, here is a URI
>   pointing to an anchor named `section_2` in an HTML document:
>
> http://example.com/html/top.html#section_2
>
> A target element can be represented by the :target pseudo-class. If
>   the document's URI has no fragment identifier, then the document has
>   no target element.

It's worth noting that `:target` [is supported in IE9+](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-sel3).